# How can I connect two agents?

Tags: anylogic

I am very new to Anylogic and am trying to send/receive information between agents, but not sure how to accomplish that. Attached please find an image which shows connections between agents. It also shows two-way connections between agents and dependent variables [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCGaL.png).

- What parameters/settings does one need to change to develop such a diagram?
- So far I have tried embedding a dynamic variable inside the agent and then drawing a connector between the agent and a dependent variable - but doing so replaces the agent icon with a dynamic variable icon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. sounds like you are best off doing some more AnyLogic tutorials, especially the SD ones, but others as well. There are example models showing you agent communication. Or rephrase your question be to more specific. "How can I do this diagram" is not a good question. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :-) Happy to help

Comment: Thank you. My question is if I define 2 single agents, can I connect them graphically with a connector and use that same connector to pass messages. When I draw a connector between two agents, it does not get connected at either ends. Putting a port inside both agents, allows me to connect the agents, but at the higher level, the agent default symbol is replaced with a port. I do not understand why connecting two agents has to be so complicated in Anylogic. What I am trying to model is a plant control system; a DCS sends a command to turn on/off a chiller and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot connect agents graphically with connectors (except in special cases).

Normally, you use the "Agent Link" objects to establish agent connections and send messages. In short, you do the following:

1. drag it into agent type 1
2. Set it up to connect to agent type 2
3. when it asks to create a corresponding Agent Link object in type 2, agree

Now, you have a way to connect agents using the agent link object.

Do check the AnyLogic help and tutorials on that, there is a lot of info on how to use them.

Comment: I have been unsuccessful in using ports to send and receive messages. My simple model file can be found at this link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a7uhdqdo0byt3cv/AABhE7B4OwvmlRBw0I1JBA-ya?dl=0> All I want to accomplish is that when the Chiller temperature matches desired temperature, a message is send via portA to a particular agent which then causes a state change. What am I missing? How does Anylogic know which port to send the message to (in case there were multiple ports connected to that port)?

Comment: You do not send messages via ports but via "Agent Link" objects, see my reply above ;-) . Ports are to send agents between different flowcharts (and are somewhat antiquated). You can do exactly what you want with "Agent Links". See the help and tutorials to learn how, it is all there for you :-)